# Can I create a 3D plot with geom_bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, presentation

Let's say that I have a dataframe

```
df  = data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5],
                 y = c(100,225,150,275,125))
df
```

Would it be possible to make a plot as the one uploaded in the question using geon_bar ? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: No, geom_bar won't allow you to do that (the areas in your graph are not rectangles, and geom_bar is based on a rectangle geometry). Check for example https://clauswilke.com/dataviz/no-3d.html, and find out why 3D visualisation is not a good idea in this case.

Comment: Here is a package that can make 3D ggplots. https://www.tylermw.com/3d-ggplots-with-rayshader/ But your plot won't do - it only has one dimension and that really doesn't need to be plotted in 3D

Comment: Very informative thank you so much